# Gaussian Elimination without interchanging rows

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

For simplicity, let $A$ be an invertible matrix over field $F$.

Elementary matrix $E_{ij}(a)$ is obtained by inserting $a$ in $(ij)$-th place of identity matrix.

*We do not consider row interchanging matrices.*

**Question:** How to prove/disprove: *With left multiplication by (finite) sequence of $E_{ij}(a)$'s to $A$, we can arrive at a diagonal matrix.*

Comment: These elementary matrices simulate subtracting a multiple of one row from another one.

Comment: (Para. from Abstract-Algebra- Grillet):  *As long as rows are not permuted or multiplied by scalars, Gauss-Jordan reduction is equivalent to left multiplication by elementary matrices. Therefore, if M is an invertible matrix, then there are elementary matrices $E_1,E_2,\cdots, E_k$ such that $E_1E_2\cdots E_kM$ is diagonal.*

Comment: Elementary matrices are supposed to be invertible, so that rules out my "trivial" solution. And the original matrix is supposed to be invertible, but my $A$ isn't. --- You need to add "invertible" to your question then.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: ... and now I'll add the answer I was typing up when I came up with my "counterexample" ...

Comment: Thanks Heckman for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Now, assuming that $A$ is $n\times n$ and invertible ... Here's a procedure (given without proof, which should be easy); repeat it for all $i$'s from 1 to $n$:

- If $A_{i,i}=0$, find a $j>i$ such that $A_{j,i}\not=0$.$^*$ (If there is no such $j$, then $A$ is not invertible.) Then add row $j$ to row $i$.
- For each $k\not=i$, add a multiple of row $i$ to row $k$, so that the entry $A_{k,i}$ becomes zero. (This is possible because you're working with entries in a field, and $A_{i,i}\not=0$.)

Note that after you perform this step with $i$ varying from 1 to $m$, then the first $m$ columns of $A$ will look like a diagonal matrix.

$^*$ This is where I stopped writing the proof before; I wondered how I could assume that $j>i$, because if $j<i$, the first column will get messed up.

Comment: So, it is like this: in first column, some down-most entry $a_{k1}$ is non-zero. With $a_{k1}$, make entries above it zero; bring  $a_{k1}$ to $(11)$ position; with the help of new $a_{11}$, make $a_{k1}$  zero, and continue such procedure in second column, ...

Comment: Yep, except you don't move $A_{k,1}$ up in general.

Answer (score 0):

[[Answered before "invertibility" was added to $A$.]] I think some assumptions are missing here. It's either impossible or trivial.

OOH, if you're forbidding $i=j$ in your matrices, you can let $A=\pmatrix{1&1\\ 0&0}$. No matter which row operations you use, you will always get a nonzero matrix where the two columns are the same.

OTOH, if you're allowing elementary matrices where $i=j$, then it's trivial: $E_{1,1}(0) \cdot E_{2,2}(0) \cdot \cdots \cdot E_{n,n}(0) = 0$, and $0A=0$ definitely is diagonal.

Comment: Thanks for notification of error. I have posted the paragraph from a book, which I couldn't clarify.